# "Стать" versus specific verbs

Tags: значения, глаголы

Сonsider these 3 sentences that contain стала (feminine past tense form of стать):

1) **Она стала к конвейеру.**
*She worked on the assembly line.*

2) **Я стала в очередь за сосисками.**
*I got in line to buy hot dogs.*

3) **Я стала на ковёр в спальне.**
*I stood on the carpet in the bedroom.*

стать is quite versatile. For example, it appears to replace работать (to work) in sentence 1, and стоять (to stand) in sentence 3.

How can стать mean so many things? When is it appropriate to use стать versus more specific verbs?

Comment: What is your native language? I bet it has a lot of words with a lot of meanings.

Comment: I think there should be **встала** instead of **стала** in all three phrases.

Comment: @Eugene  "Стать" [is possible](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x) too.

Comment: @Alex.S My native language is English

Comment: OK, so think e.g. about "to get" which can mean "to receive", "to become", "to understand", "to buy", "to achieve", "to hear" [and so on](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/get).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, there is no contradiction, and **стать** does not have that many meanings as your English translations of those sentences suggest.

**Стать** is a perfective verb that generally means 'to stand', and since it is perfective, the connotations are '*to come to a place and remain standing there*', so:

> 1) *Она стала к конвейеру* means 'She came up to the assembly line and remained working there.' = 'She began working at the assembly line.'
>
> 2) *Я стала в очередь за сосисками* means 'I came up to the line to buy hot dogs and remained standing there.' = 'I stood into the line to buy hot dogs.'
>
> 3) *Я стала на ковёр в спальне* means 'I came into the bedroom, stood onto the carpet there, and remained standing on it.' = 'I stood on the carpet in the bedroom.'

Comment: **стать** often used to 'to became'.  Я стала актрисой/матерью/красавицей — I became an actress/a mother/a beauty. 'to stand' — **встать**, **стоять**.

Comment: @Eugene - That's another meaning of this verb, the question wasn't about it.

Comment: @YellowSky How would you interpret **Он стал на защиту обиженных**? Maybe *He stood for the defense of the oppressed*?

Comment: @ycele - **Он стал на защиту обиженных** is "He _stood up_ to defend the offended the oppressed (_and remained their_)". So what?

Comment: @YellowSky I came across this sentence in my book, which was translated there as *He came to the defense of the upset person.* I suspected that I could substitute *He came* with *He stood*, but wanted to double check with you. Your interpretation of the 3 sentences in your answer, and now this one, has helped me understand стать better.